# Create sharepoint user and log them in via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sharepoint

I have a public SaaS application. Users can signup and create and manipulate data records, etc. I also have a sharepoint server. I have an 'admin' user on the Sharepoint site. My SaaS app can log onto the Sharepoint server using the admin login and upload download files. That is all fairly straight forward.

What I want to be able to do is (1) programmatically create individual logins on Sharepoint for my SaaS users, (2) be able to log them in a serve them a links to sharepoints document so that they can 'live edit' them in Word. I want my app to be able to control which users can access and edit which documents.

The users are not all part of a single organisation, so I don't think I can use Active Directory. But I don't really know anything about Activie Directory, so that may not be true.

Does that make any sense? Is that even possible? I've done a lot of searching online but can't find anything that seems to achieve that. My alternative is to implement some sort of WebDav server, but having looked at that as an option, I think it makes more sense to try and integrate with the existing Sharepoint server.

Any help or pointers would be very gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to user Office 365. If yes, then think you should explore Microsoft Graph API. It allows you n number of options to connect the Microsoft 365 products including SharePoint Online and Identity/user management.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet, I will look into that.